# Failed to Instantiate LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Java : Open JDK 11.

Hibernate : 5.4.10.Final

Spring : 5.2.5.RELEASE

Tomcat :9.0.39

All the Respective Properties are well defined.

Configuration :

```xml
<bean id="testentityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="testDataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testPersistanceUnit"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="testHibernateProperties"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Stack Trace :

```
 Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: 
 Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
                at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4902)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5211)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1848)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: First Spring 5.0 doesn't (officially) support java 11 (only up to Java 10), secondly you appear to have conflicting versions in your dependencies (although I'm not entirely sure if Spring 5.0 supports Hibernate 5.2 or only up to 5.1 (there have been some incompatible changes between hibernate 5.1 and 5.2 IIRC). Thirdly Spring 5.0 has had no support for over a year I would strongly suggest to upgrade to 5.2 or 5.3 (which support up to Java 15 and hibernate 5.2 for certain).

Comment: Facing the Same With Updated Stack :

Spring : 5.2.5.RELEASE
Hibernate : 5.4.10.Final

Comment: I also mentioned you probably have incompatible libraries. You only mention Spring (I would upgrade to the latests of the 5.2 branch and not some in between version). If those are pulling in older/incompatible jars it won't work. Please add your list of dependencies (your pom.xml for instance) to the question. And please leave the formatting as is.